# How to change page Zimbra Web Client login

Tags: zimbra

I was beginning to learn about Zimbra.
I want to change the look of the login page, but do not know how to do it - which folders and files do I have to edit?

I searched on Google and Zimbra communities, but found no answers.

Answer (score 0):

yoursftpZimbra/opt/zimbra/jetty-distribution-9.1.5.v20140505/webapps/zimbra/skins/_base/logos

otherelse to change predifined size of the logo client side:

yoursftpZimbra/opt/zimbra/jetty-distribution-9.1.5.v20140505/webapps/zimbra/skins/_base/base3/skin.properties

line 98:
LoginBanner         =   @img(, LoginBannerImg, 440px, 60px)@

line 108:
AppBanner           =   @AppBannerPos@ @img(, AppBannerImg, 200px, 35px)@